# How to initialize a float literal in dart

Tags: dart, types, floating-point

It seems I can't initialize a constant float without strange errors.

```
Float a = 2; //A value of type 'int' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Float'
Float a = 2.0; //A value of type 'double' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Float'
```

How do I initialize a float other than just using a double?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to use FFI? If not, floats are not a thing in Dart. `double` is the only floating-point type.

Comment: In C, this is done with `float a = 2.0f`.  Not sure if that applies here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dart auto-imported the package 'dart:ffi', leading me to think Float is a native type. It isn't and double is the only floating point type.
@Christopher Moore's comment let me find the problem.